# Jenkins HTTPrqeuest plugin verbose mode?

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I would like to see the SSL handshake in detail for failed requests. I am using the [HttpRequest Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) for Jenkins. Does anyone know of something that could resemble "-v" for curl commands?

Here is a sample request that will fail using the plugin, within a declarative pipeline:

```
    def response = 
            httpRequest url: 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/',
            httpMode: 'GET',
            customHeaders: [[name: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/json']]
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Verbose option build into the HTTP Request plugin. But as a workaround may be you can enable debug logs for the underline libraries.(e.g: HTTP Apache Client etc.)

To answer your specific question since you need SSL debug logs. You can enable SSL debug logs for the JVM. You can pass the following System property to the Jenkins runtime. If you want to filter logs for a specific host refer [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/973783).

```
 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```